# Dynamic Range with Categorical Variables

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, time-series

I'd like to sort a time series of exam performance by one of three categories:

[image: GRE Score Performance]

Ideally, a function would sort the scores by "difficulty" while still preserving chronological order. I'd like to do this without filters etc. Something like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/) is very close, but not quite there. Do I need to use dynamic ranges? Or can I just define data ranges in the table dialog with VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH?

I'm thinking a bar graph would be the easiest way to illustrate the data, but I'm open to suggestions. New scores are added every day, with varying difficulties.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/714vmlsiykx1id7/QBank%20Scores.xlsx?dl=0) is the spreadsheet if anyone would like to look it over.

---

EDIT:

The output visualization could be, for example, a clustered bar graph, but with only one label per category. The idea is that I'd like to preserve chronological order without necessarily having to mark it on the graph.

[image][image]

Would there, for instance, be a quick-and easy and formula-driven way to put these 14 and 17 values for "score" all together under one label? I feel like 17 bar graphs clustered too closely would be hard to read.

I realize this is more of a formatting than a formula issue, but I appreciate input with regards to both.

Comment: Is the Auto Filter out of the question?  This is what you get from Data->Filter in the Ribbon.  Sorting without using filters is going to be difficult.  If the end goal is visualizing the data, you may be able to let the chart sort it for you. Can you give a better picture of what the output should be and if viz is the final goal, some idea of what you want that to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you add a `Table` over the data in the workbook.  One for verbal and one for math.  The upside is that it will automatically grow with your data as you add new rows.  This is very helpful because charts and other things will automatically refer to the new data.  Add one with CTRL+T or Insert->Table on the Ribbon.

Once you have the Table, you can easily do the sorting bit by adding a two column sort onto the Table.  This menu is accessible by right clicking in the Table and doing Sort->Custom Sort.  Again, the Table is nice here because it will only sort the data within it (not the whole sheet) and will remember your settings.  This lets you add new data and simply do Data->Reapply to get it to sort again.  Your sort on Difficulty is going to be alphabetic unless you add a number at the front.  Here is the sorting step:

[image: sorting with table]

With this done, you can create a quick chart based on that data.  For the "implicit chronology" you can simply plot score vs. difficulty for all of them since they are sorted.

[image: chart with scores]

To get closer to that matrix style display, you can easily create a PivotTable based on this Table and let it do the organizing by date/difficulty.  Here is the result of that.  I am using `Average` as the aggregation function since it appears that no dates have more than 1 score.  If they did, it would be a better choice than `Sum`.

[image: Pivot Table of data]

Comment: This is great - and very, very close to what I need. Unfortunately, there are multiple scores (across difficulties) towards the end of the dataset. I end up getting a PivotTable like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttjvhqmx0mdlx1z/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-22%20at%2011.44.52%20AM.png?dl=0) and a chart like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lq6jkgt3o5cs194/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-22%20at%2011.43.06%20AM.png?dl=0) or [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/345krzikz0bjjf2/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-22%20at%2011.49.18%20AM.png?dl=0). Any feedback on how to optimize this would be greatly appreciated!